# AngularJS - Two-way binding with directive that takes variable number of parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an inline-editor directive that takes a whole slew of parameters (wrapped into one big object to keep things clean). So far I have this on the parent scope:

```
$scope.inlineEditParams = {
    rendererUrl: null,
    content: {
        body: {
             selector: "#content-body",
             value: $scope.content.body
        }
    }
};
```

This is how I'm injecting the directive in the template:

```
<div inline-edit params="inlineEditParams"></div>
```

And I take the parameter onto the scope of the directive in the obvious way:

```
scope: {
    params: '='
}
```

So obviously changes to the inlineEditParams object are reflected in both the directive and parent controller. But how can I get two-way binding going between the parent $scope.content.body and the inlineEditParams.content.body values, so that changes by either the parent controller or the directive will be reflected on both immediately? I don't want to pass in the parent $scope.content, since the directive expects the parameters to be formatted a specific way.

Comment: I think inside directive, you can use watchCollection method to watch changes to parameters.

Comment: I know I can $watch everything, but it feels like a hack. I basically want to say on the parent scope $scope.content.body == $scope.inlineEditParams.content.body.value, and have them bound to each other in both directions

Comment: I haven't tried this but I think it will work. I assume parent $scope.content.body is a string which is a primitive type. Can you try to change it to object & then assign it to directive parameters? It should get the two way binding going.e.g. $scope.inlineEditParams.content =